# 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'function result' on Dart

Tags: dart

```
class FilterOption {

  int year = 0;

  String? get yearText {
    print("year $year");
    return "$year ~";
  }
}
```

When I call yearText, it throws error.

```
 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'function result'
```

What I tried

```
return "${0} ~"; -> works fine

String year = "" -> works fine

String? yearText() { -> same error
```

What's wrong with my code??
Looks perfectly fine for me..

Comment: What is the line number? I presume it's 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed 'year' to another name then it worked.